# How to open copied url in the browser?

Tags: typescript, jasmine, protractor

I am testing a page that generates urls. I can copy the url to clipboard by clicking on an icon on the page. But I can't figure out how to open it in the browser. I need to do this test in several different browsers. 
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: if you share what you tried so far and what errors you encountered that may help. Right now, the question is too broad

Answer (score 0):

You can get the url by the icon and assign it to a variable, then open the browser with the variable.

Comment: can you help me with the syntax to assign it to a variable? I'm not quite sure how to do it. I copy the link with "this.copyLink.click();"